# How do we debug our APIs written using Grape API?

Tags: ruby

I have built my API using the Grape API, would like to know how to debug it...

Comment: Hi Unspecified, do you mind telling us more about what you are exactly trying to debug? It'll help someone give you a much better answer.

Comment: I mean the way we debug javascript using breakpoints in chrome, can we do the same in ruby ? I'd like to dig into a function or jump to next function call and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Install RubyMine and go to 'run'-> 'edit configurations'. 
2.Click on the plus sign on the left corner of the window and select the configuration you want.
3. Name your configuration in the 'Name' textbox at the top and edit any default settings you want to change.
4. Apply breakpoints and run your server using the debugger mode. You are good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write tests for Grape APIs with either Rack or Rails, which should help you verify that the output is what you expected.

https://github.com/intridea/grape#writing-tests

I'm not sure if it works with Sinatra/Grape, but you could also add in [Simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) to make sure you've covered your bases.

If you've already written tests and still have an issue, can you provide additional detail on the error you are getting?

Comment: I am able to run the tests successfully, I just wanted to know if there is some tool for ruby like firebug / chrome debugger for javascript, wherein we can apply breakpoints & stuff

Comment: its too bad when you cant run a console and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [racksh gem](https://github.com/sickill/racksh). It allows you start a development console similar to `bundle exec rails console` in Rails.